# Geometric Effect of Multiplying an Orthogonal Matrix by a Non-Zero Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, orthogonality, reflection

> We are giving a matrix $Q=\frac{1}{9}\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 8 & 4  \\ 4 & 4 & -7 \\ 8 & -1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$

The question askes to describe, without any further caclulation, the geometric effect of multiplying a non-zero vector by $Q$.

I have shown that $Q$ is a reflection combined by a rotation, as $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and det($Q)=-1$. But I do not understand what multiplying $Q$ by a non-zero vector would achieve.

Comment: It would produce a new vector of the same length as the original one - the result of rotating and reflecting it. What more do you want?

Comment: The answer that is given is a rotation of $180°$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Not at all. Take $(1,0,0)$ for instance, it is clearly not turned into its negative.